# Why can't I split special char using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select with option value of `*|||*`. When I split this value it seems the `*` cannot be stored in `label id`. If I change the value to `xxx|||yyy` the value is stored. This is some of my script:

```
var tujuan = $(this).val().split('|||');
var val_t  = tujuan[0];
var txt_t  = tujuan[1];

txt_tujuan  = "<label id='"+val_t+"' class='label label-primary lbl_txt' cursor:pointer;'>";
txt_tujuan += txt_t
txt_tujuan += "</label>";

$('#d_tujuan').find('label').each(function(){
  curr_label = $(this).attr('id');

  alert(curr_label);
});
```

Comment: `"*|||*".split('|||');` returns `["*", "*"]`. Are you sure it's the value you are expecting? Also note that `"*"` is **not** a [valid value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) for an HTML id attribute. Along with this id's must be unique, so they both can't be `"*"`

Comment: yes. I that result is what I expected. so, in the `label id` and `label text` has `*` as its value

Comment: @ashura91 In `id` you can't have special characters except `_` (underscore) and `-`(hypen)

Comment: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](//stackoverflow.com/q/70579)

Comment: ok guys. thank you so much for responding my question.  should I delete this question or what?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek well, I tried to create unique label. So, I store the value in id

Comment: you can store unique value in html tag using valid `data-*` attribute, for example: `<label data-pengarang="Taufik"> ... </label>`